# Mocking a custom class with Mockery in Laravel 4

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, mockery

Using Laravel 4.2, I've got a custom class `TestyClass` in `/app/libraries`.

Using Mockery and PHPUnit, I am attempting to mock this class, but my Mock doesn't seem to register.

When I run the test, I get `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method testymethod() from Mockery_0_TestyClass should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

My Controller that I am testing runs `TestyClass::testymethod();`, and the Log::info inside of `testymethod()` runs correctly.

**What am I missing to register a Mock of a custom class in Laravel 4.2?**

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('TestyClass');
$mock->shouldReceive('testymethod')->once();
```

**TestyClass:**

```
class TestyClass {
    public static function testymethod() {
        Log::info('----=-=-=-=--=in heyhey!@!!=-=-=-=-=-=-=-12312312312312341');
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('TestyClass');
```

Creates a new class that extends `TestyClass`, adding the behaviour necessary to mock etc, then creates and instance of it and returns it, so $mock is an instance of `Mockery_0_TestyClass`

You're then telling mockery that you expect that *instance* to receive a call to the `testymethod`, but you're actually making a static call to the `TestyClass` class method. You can do this with mockery, but it's not very good, I wouldn't recommend doing so and you'll probably want to run your tests with process isolation.

```
$mock = Mockery::mock('alias:TestyClass');
```

Comment: Yeah, like you said about it not being very good, the `alias` worked for my dummy TestyClass, but when applied to my real and extensive `Lib` class, it broke: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function __call() on a non-object in /Users/lukeshaheen/Dropbox/WWW/Phone2Action 2.0/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Loader/EvalLoader.php(16) : eval()'d code on line 633`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your controller?
There is a difference in testing a class method and testing a controller.
If you are testing the controller then try using `$this->call` - example;

```
class TestyClassTest extends TestCase {

  public function setUp()
  {
    $this->mock = $this->mock('TestyClass');
  }

  /* Move method to TestCase.php */
  public function mock($class)
  {
    $mock = Mockery::mock($class);
    $this->app->instance($class, $mock);
    return $mock;
  }

  /* Move method to TestCase.php */
  public function tearDown()
  {
    Mockery::close();
  }

  public function testIfTestyControllerRunsTestyMethodAndReturnsOk()
  {
    // Step 3. Arrange
    // Last we arrange our test

    $this->mock->shouldReceive('testymethod')->once();

    // Step 2. Act
    // Then we write how we the results will be asserted.
    // The route should correspond with the controller executing the class method.
    // Eg. TestyMethodController@test; return $this->class->testymethod()

    **$this->call('GET', 'TestyController@test');**

    // Step 1. Assert
    // Start by writing the results we expect;
    // If the controller issues no Exceptions we should get a response header status 200.

    $this->assertResponseOk();
  }
}
```

Essentially $mock->shouldReceive is setting a listener on the mock object, it is waiting for the method to be run - if it runs then everything is okay, otherwise you get an InvalidCountException.

Hope that helps, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issue: the class was not recognized. Try to use __construct method to initialize it. That worked for me. (It didn't work setting it up in setUp method).

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->mock = Mockery::mock('TestyClass');
}
```

and then just call in test method:

```
$this->mock->shouldReceive('testymethod')->once();
```